# Google Apps Script/Google Sheet Bug? Copying/Re-Setup Data Validation refering to named range does not work on duplicated Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

[SEE THIS EXAMPLE HERE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D2uhSZzXrFmo8bVym7ynSwcNklWCyMWI8a563AMdpNw/edit?usp=sharing)

Situation:
Data validation on cells that refer to a range via direct reference (A1Notation) and Data Validation on other cells that refer to a named range.

Works both.

When duplicating the sheet, both still work. However, when resetting the data validations manually to the same ranges or via my script, the data validation of the cell where the data validation refers via named range will not work and there is no way to set it up again by referring via named range either manually or by copying (.getDataValidation / .setDataValidation) via script.

Check out the example - run script function cp_dataValidation() either on Sheet1 and Copy of Sheet1 as an active sheet. Then click the data validation dropdowns in the cells.

[image]

Eventually, my goal is to perform a copy of the data validation (referring to a named range) from one range to another on a duplicated sheet via script.

```
function cp_dataValidation() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()

  //cell with data validation referring to a named range
  var named_range_tmpl = sheet.getRange("B2");
  //cell with data validation referring to a range via A1Notation
  var range_tmpl = sheet.getRange("C2");

  //target cells to copy dataValidation to
  var nr_target = sheet.getRange("D2");
  var r_target = sheet.getRange("E2");


  nr_target.setDataValidation(named_range_tmpl.getDataValidation());
  r_target.setDataValidation(range_tmpl.getDataValidation());


  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(named_range_tmpl.getDataValidation(), null, 2));
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(range_tmpl.getDataValidation(), null, 2));
}
```

Comment: About ``the data validation of the cell where the data validation refers via named range will not work``, when I used your sample Spreadsheet and your script (run ``cp_dataValidation()``), unfortunately, I couldn't replicate your situation. Can I ask you about the method for replicating your issue? By the way, can you add your script in your question?

Comment: Did you try the data validation drop downs on both sheets?

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating your question. I could replicate your situation. So I proposed a workaround as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that is not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to copy the Data Validation including the named range as the values.

If my understanding is correct, how about this workaround? It seems that `nr_target.setDataValidation(named_range_tmpl.getDataValidation())` cannot be used for the named range of other sheet. So as a workaround, how about using the method of `copyTo()`?

#### Modified script:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var source = sheet.getRange("B2:C2");
var target = sheet.getRange("D2:E2");
source.copyTo(target, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_DATA_VALIDATION);
target.clearContent(); // or target.clear({contentsOnly: true}); // Added
```

#### Note:

- Please test the script for both sheets.
- If you want to copy both the value and Data Validation, please use `source.copyTo(target)` instead of `source.copyTo(target, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_DATA_VALIDATION)`.

#### Reference:

- [copyTo(destination, copyPasteType, transposed)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination-copypastetype-transposed)

Comment: Not much time atm to inspect - however I want to refer to the named range within the new copied sheet. Actually I just want to copy data validation from one cell(that refers dv via named range) to the other, within the duplicated sheet.

Comment: the copyTo with DATA_VAL ENUM is a good idea, i will try that when I am home.

Comment: WORKS! However, copies the currently set value as well.

Comment: @haemse Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I forgot to clear the content after the copy. I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: @haemse Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: @haemse Is there anything that I can do for your question? If my answer was not useful for your situation. I have to apologize and modify it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. I would like to think of about the solution.

Comment: no thanks, that source.copyTo(target, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_DATA_VALIDATION) was the solution! thanks

Comment: maybe you can also vote up my question, since the problem exits, the usecase is there and a solution was found.